# jQuery Mobile page implementation and hash navigation conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery 1.9.1 and jQuery Mobile 1.4.2.

I have a problem with my jQM site that causes data-rel="back" links to break. Originally I thought this was some other problem but I have found the cause of this.

My website consists of an index page which contains the header and the body, which looks like:

```
<div data-role="header">
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="login">
</div>
<div data-role="footer">
</div>
```

The login page does contain login forms and other elements but that is not important for this problem.

The other pages are simply html files that have:

```
<div data-role="page" id="pageId">
    content
</div>
```

My javascript file then loads those files into the DOM:

```
$("body").pagecontainer("load", "page.html");
```

Then, all links do their usual navigation:

```
<a href="#pageID">Link</a>
```

And that performs normally.

The problem is that if you refresh on a page, for example `#pageThree`, the site reloads, and takes you to the login page, but the URL keeps `#pageThree`, but since it doesn't exist at load time it is ignored. This is my desired behavior. However, I then use the link

```
<a href="#pageFour">Link</a>
```

to go to `#pageFour` which has a link:

```
<a href="#" data-rel="back">Back to pageThree</a>
```

Now, if I press that "back" button, it should take me to `#pageThree`, however since I refreshed on that page, the back button takes me back to the login page.

So in short: If I refresh on a page with a hash navigation, any back buttons that point to that page redirect to the initial login page instead.

I may have done an improper implementation of pageload and am open to suggestions, as long as it makes back buttons work properly.

Comment: first of all, refresh in Browser is very bad, because jQuery Mobile fetch all the internal and external pages into the initial mobile pagecontainer. Your should take a look at your redirect function to login. The back button takes you back to your last nav-hash, so the question is, is last nav-hash your login page? or is it redirect to the login again? Alternatively you can upgrade to jQM 1.4.3 and jQ 1.11.1 to test if it is still an issue.

Comment: @YingdingWang The normal function of the app is not meant to refresh, but it is something user's will inevitably do. I have 'fixed' this problem now though, by setting `$.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;`

Comment: that's a good option, thanks for share this with us.